# Script not working since windows 7

Tags: python, windows-7

I have the following script which worked fine on XP, since I have a new PC on Windows 7 Professional the code has stopped working

```
import os           
import shutil
from time import strftime

logsdir="c:\logs"
zipdir="c:\logs\puttylogs\zipped_logs"
zip_program="zip.exe"

for files in os.listdir(logsdir):
  if files.endswith(".log"):
    files1=files+"."+strftime("%Y-%m-%d")+".zip"
    os.chdir(logsdir)
    os.system(zip_program + " " +  files1 +" "+ files)
    shutil.move(files1, zipdir)
    os.remove(files)
```

The error I am getting is 
        U:>python logs.py
                zip warning: name not matched: ping_dms_155.log

```
zip error: Nothing to do! (ping_dms_155.log.2013-05-14.zip)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "logs.py", line 24, in <module>
    shutil.move(files1, zipdir)
  File "c:\python27\lib\shutil.py", line 301, in move
    copy2(src, real_dst)
  File "c:\python27\lib\shutil.py", line 130, in copy2
    copyfile(src, dst)
  File "c:\python27\lib\shutil.py", line 82, in copyfile
    with open(src, 'rb') as fsrc:
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'ping_dms_155.log.2013-05-14.zip'
```

I can't think why it would stop working, thanks in advance

Comment: Did you change Python version aswell?

Comment: Used to be 2.7.2 now on 2.7.4

Comment: Set access permissions on `c:\logs\` ?

Comment: I have access to the directory, I can zip them manually

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got this to work by changing the os.system to subprocess so the code now looks like

```
import os   
import shutil
from time import strftime
import subprocess

logsdir="c:\logs"
zipdir="c:\logs\puttylogs\zipped_logs"
zip_program="zip.exe"

for files in os.listdir(logsdir): 
    if files.endswith(".log"):
        files1=files+"."+strftime("%Y%m%d")+".zip"
        os.chdir(logsdir)
        subprocess.call([zip_program,files1, files])
        shutil.move(files1, zipdir)
        os.remove(files)
```

Comment: Thanks to everyone for their help

Answer (score 0):

It seems you do have `zip.exe` on your windows 7 machine from the error, but it may not be a version compatible with Windows 7.

Check in `logsdir` to see if the file you modify (`ping_dms_155.log.2013-05-14.zip`) already exists. If all of these are true I would suggest using python module `zipfile`.

Comment: It will work manually from the command line C:\logs>zip ping_dms_155.2013-05-14.log.zip ping_dms_155.log
  adding: ping_dms_155.log (160 bytes security) (deflated 89%)

Comment: zip ping_dms_155.2013-05-14.log.zip ping_dms_155.log, the parameter ping_dms_155.2013-05-14.log.zip seems different from files1, files1 is ping_dms_155.log.2013-05-14.zip. It could be that the file name is not allowed with "." followed by "-". Try naming the file like files1 = files.split(".")[0] + "-" + strftime("%Y-%m-%d")+".zip"

Comment: could you print files1 in your code and check if its the same what is in logsdir? If they are different that should be the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your path strings aren't escaped properly.

```
logsdir="c:\logs"
zipdir="c:\logs\puttylogs\zipped_logs"
```

should be:

```
logsdir=r"c:\logs"
zipdir=r"c:\logs\puttylogs\zipped_logs"
```

The directory c:ogs doesn't exist. Running it manually worked because you changed to the log directory. It ran on XP because... well, you didn't run this exact script on XP because it wouldn't work there either.

Comment: Adding that doesn't change it, it still errors the same.  I have the two machine running at the moment and the XP one is working